# How safe is Internal Storage?

Tags: java, android

#### What I need:

For Android: I need to save data permanently, but also be able to edit (and obviously read) it. This data should NOT be accessible by the user - it can contain things like a highscore, which must not be edited by the user.

#### My Problem

I would have (and have already) used `Internal Storage`, but I´m not sure how safe it actually is. [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) it says:

> You can save files directly on the device's internal storage. By
>   default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your
>   application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the
>   user). When the user uninstalls your application, these files are
>   removed.

That´s basicly exactly what I need - **but is it really safe?** Can it be accessed (maybe only read?) through a rooted device? (Or any other way?)

What about SQLite-Databases or Shared Memory? Are they better suited for saving (small amounts of) data?

Also: is it generally recommended to handle "secret" data in a different way internally? (like not saving it (internally) as Integer/String but some kind of encrypted)

Comment: When in doubt, use encryption!

Comment: This has been asked many, many times. If a user is rooted, they can see/change anything. If you want to make it harder, encrypt it. Even then, you have to store your key somewhere, so a dedicated person can crack it.

Comment: Nothing is safe on a rooted device. The root user can access & modify any file, database, ... even memory (but typical user would not know how). Encryption helps but advanced users could decompile your apk and extract the crypt part.

Comment: So the only "really" safe storage option would be anywhere but on the device itself? (like on a webserver - still not completely safe, but that´s another topic)

Comment: Yes, that's basically right. It just depends on *how much* security you want. If it's just for a personal high score list, go for internal/sharedprefs. Who cares if the user edits their own score? If it goes on a leaderboard somewhere, store it wherever the leaderboard is(server).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can it be accessed (maybe only read?) through a rooted device?

It can be read from and written to.

> it can contain things like a highscore, which must not be edited by the user.

It is the user's data, not yours. It is the user's device, not yours. Hence, the user can edit that data if the user wants, so long as their data is stored on their device.

Now, if you wanted to prevent *somebody else* from editing that data, then encryption, with a user-supplied password, is a reasonable measure. That would seem unnecessary for a game high score.

Otherwise, if you do not want them editing that data, do not store it on their device.

Comment: If it´s a global highscore on some ladder, I wouldnt even let the user edit it. (would be cheating and not fair for everyone else)

Comment: @BenjaminSchwalb: Either this is a *local copy* of a "global highscore" (in which case the user editing it would not matter, and it would get rewritten by you anyway after some later network operation), or you have a very strange architecture where some random user happens to hold the master copy of your high scores.

Comment: The highscore was just an example - let´s take the userid: i need to save it somewhere locally, and pass it to the DB to know which user to update - this also must not be changed (it´s assigned automatically once, and should stay unchanged) -- or maybe a config-file, where I store things like "how much score/gold/... do I get for xy", these must never be edited either. (just examples, probably there are better ways to do all this, but that´s not really the question here)

Comment: @BenjaminSchwalb: Either the user ID is something the user already knows (and therefore is tied to a password and is not something that the user can change sans the password for the other account), or the user ID is a 50+ character generated string (and therefore the user is statistically unlikely to be able to modify to come up with a valid value). With regards to the "config-file", either don't store game rules locally or live with the fact that miscreants can manipulate those rules.

Comment: So the answer remains simplified: nothing is safe on the device, not even the code

Comment: @BenjaminSchwalb: Yes. Welcome to client-side programming. :-) Having light barricades (e.g., putting data on internal storage, so you have to have root to mess with the data) is fine, especially where those barricades are "low-hanging fruit" from a level-of-development-effort standpoint. And I'd invest in an architecture that maximizes flexibility for you to change client-side or server-side implementations of your initial logic. Beyond that, wait to see if your game is a success before investing tons o' time in trying to erect further barricades; they only matter if you actually have users.

Answer (score 2):

Using SharedPreferences is what you may want. It saves data in an XML file deep in the caverns of the /data/ directory. The user or other apps can't get there unless the phone has root permissions.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: Isn´t Shared Preferences used as a Storage option accessible from different apps? Or did I just missunderstand it?

Comment: That's what I thought at first too. It's only usable from within the package I think. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: So it´s accessible just like the Internal Storage, just with xml instead of play text?

Comment: Right but android takes care of that via an incredibly simple to use API. You get the application's instance of the SharedPreferences, and start reading. Or, get an editor from the instance of SharedPreferences, write changes, and commit the edits. Quite simple - I love it! Just look at the links I gave you.

Comment: Yeah, i read them, just wasn´t sure about the access - but looks quite simple/cool to use for simple data.

Comment: SharedPreferences is using a simple xml file stored inside your app internal storage: http://pastebin.com/T1HiNmss

Comment: Yes, but `root@android`. You are root. Therefore your argument is invalid. While I agree with @Sirlate, a high score isn't something you want to protect like a credit card (unless it translates into real value/prizes. That would mean a lot more work with SSL and stuff like that.) If one of the 15% of android users that have root want to take the fun out of the game and change a number that has no bearing on real life (unless it translates into real prizes) then that's their loss, not yours.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not safe, user can modify files on rooted devices and emulator.  It's better to use Encryption, but encryption is not 100% safe, In fact experienced geeks can crack your encryption.   I suggest saving critical data which should not accessed or manipulate by user on your webserver not on user's devices.

Comment: Why an Emulator? As long as I don´t distribute the .apk, shouldn´t it be "impossible" to get it running on an Emulator? (Or can you just get the apk while downloading from GooglePlay?)

Comment: Rooted users can extract the APK from /data/app.

Comment: @benjaminschwalb Check [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handyandy.appextractor&hl=en) out.