# Protect a DB against rooted devices

Tags: java, android, database-connection

Imagine I have a game, where I need to save data for every user like level, highscore, gold,...
If I saved some of these locally (on the user´s device) they aren´t really safe and could be modified by a user with a rooted device and a bit of skill. (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813662/how-safe-is-internal-storage))

So I need to put them on a Database on my server - I´d connect to it with a webservice and JSON.

But then I realized that this isn´t any safer: If someone can get my APK, he can decompile it, get the code used to post the highscore, and either edit it to always post 1,234,567 (and compile it again) or just extract it and post any highscore.

In case of a highscore, it´s not a big problem - but with this, it´s basically possible to get/post anything that´s used in the app.

**How can I protect my App/Database against this?**

**My Ideas:**

1. Encrypt everything I post: Can´t work, as the encryption happens on
   the device
2. Encrypt everything I post with a seed from the DB: As the "hacker" can get the seed aswell, not any safer
3. Generate a key for every connection: Same as first

**In one sentence:** 
As long as a "hacker" can mirror the behaviour of my App, is there any way of ensuring that the connection to my DB is actually opened by my App and not someone else?

Comment: I think that if you store those in a `SharedPreferences` it will be visible and probably accessible from your application only.

Comment: 1) afaik it´s accessible on a rooted device 2) I need to store atleast some of the data online (like the highscore - it´s global highscore list)

Comment: Yes - you're right, this can be accessed from a rooted device - it's of no use for you. So, the scores data etc. should be put on your server and accessed each and every time online. The decompilation of an .apk file isn't anways going to give you the whole code. I've read this and there's no guarantee that one can get the whole code. Even so, if the data is protected with a password on your server, it will be harder to get without it.

Comment: But if I have a password on the server, I need to have it in the app aswell, or I can´t post anything, right? And if you can decompile it, the password isn´t safe either

Comment: You can put a `Dialog` at the beginning to load the results from the server (this should require the password to be entered manually) and then once again, to upload the new results (again with a `Dialog` and the password being entered manually). Each user will have their own passwords etc. can't this be done like that?

Comment: 1) I don´t want the user to enter a password all the time 2) if it´s the users password, he can also post it while changing the highscore manually ("hacking")

Comment: So, the only thing I can see here to be fitting your needs is to put the most important functionnalities in an encrypted library and use it. I don't know how else you can protect your property (e.g. the code) in case you suppose it's always decompilable and reusable.

Comment: Library seems like a viable option, will look into this further

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your approach to this. If you don't want the user to change the data, don't put it on their device. The server needs to be the master of the data in the example you give. Use the local database only as a cache that you use for display, then sync and validate it against your server when you can. This way it doesn't really matter if a rooted user chooses to change his devices database. All data posted to your server needs to come from an authenticated user. There is no way to make sure data isn't being tampered with locally on a users device.

Decompiling your app should not expose any way for the user to post data to your server. Let the user authenticate with your server and give him an expiring ticket/token in return. Look at [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html), and the sample SampleSyncAdapter. The official developer site has some great reading for this as well. [Handling User Data](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html#UserData)

> In general, we recommend minimizing the frequency of asking for user credentials—to make phishing attacks more conspicuous, and less likely to be successful. Instead use an authorization token and refresh it.
>
> Where possible, username and password should not be stored on the device. Instead, perform initial authentication using the username and password supplied by the user, and then use a short-lived, service-specific authorization token.

Also look at how [Signing your application](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) works to make sure only "approved" builds of the app can communicate with your server.

Comment: "If you don't want the user to change the data, don't put it on their device." In my example with a highscore, how would this be possible? I need to take the score and send it to the DB.